# Google assistant is not responding to OK Google

Tags: voice-command, google-assistant, oneplus-5t

Google assistant is not enabled on my One Plus  5T  when I say "OK Google ". I have to open google assistant app and then it starts working.

I am not able to figure the reason. How to fix this?

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

Comment: So did you go to Settings->Language & Input and Select 'Google' so that the first switch is no longer greyed out?